# Flex 4.6 Mobile App Install

Tags: android, apache-flex

I copied a tutorial like the simple Hello World App which I followed and created to try features on in Flex 4.6. It work it the emulator with the Flash Flex 4.6 software but when it cam to using / testing the simple App on a real phone there was a problem.

it installed on the HTC Wildfire S but when it came to running the app, there was a error with the following.

"The application HelloWorld(process air.HelloWorld has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

I am new to Flex but this error is making things harder, It seems this is a unknown error the code seem to be all correct I checked it with the tutorial.

The HTC That I tested on has the following os

Android version 2.3.5
Software number 2.13.206.1
Kernel version 2.6.35.10

Do you know any common reason for this error, the firmware is the latest 2.3.5

Thanks

Comment: How did you install the app?  Did you launch a "debug on device" from Flash Builder?  Or something else?

Comment: I tried it using the debug mode in Flash Builder , It tried to run the app on my phone but the same error. So then I tried to also export the created App which it did, saved it to  the SD card then installed it on the phone , but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If i could i would just comment this, but anyways...

I have few working Flex mobile apps which i tested on android devices. Yesterday i only had my friends HTC sense 2.3.3 (which i didnt used before) available for testing. None of my working AIR apps did work on that phone. I am always using captive runtime. App size is usually around 10 mb apk, and 20 mb when installed (even small hello world app always have about 20mb when installed with captive runtime). Strange thing is, that apps on HTC sense had only 10 mb after being installed - so there was clearly some problem with deploying captive runtime...

If your hello world works on flash builder simulator, then its probably some problem with device.

You should try another devices.

You should also check, if your app size is around 20mb...